# cookies are not being set with nodeJs and Varcel

Tags: reactjs, node.js, azure, express, vite

Hello everyone i am facing a really annoying bug

i deployed my back end to azure and front end to varcel

i am trying to send a JWT token to my front end from my back end

LOGIN ROUTE

```js
router.post("/login", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { username, password } = req.body;
    const user = await User.findOne({
      where: {
        userName: username,
      },
    });

    if (user) {
      const match = await bcrypt.compare(
        password,
        user.getDataValue("passWord")
      );
      if (match) {
        const token = createToken(user.id);
        res.cookie("jwt", token, {
          httpOnly: false,
          maxAge: maxAge * 1000,
          sameSite: "lax",
          secure: true,
        });
        res.status(200).json({ user });
      } else {
        res.status(400).json({ message: "Invalid username or password" });
      }
    } else {
      res.status(400).json({ message: "Invalid username or password" });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    next(error); // Pass any errors to the error handling middleware
  }
});
```

when i log in the JWT being send to the website but not saved
https://claim-work.vercel.app/login
you can try to login with
user
user
it can login but its cant read the jwt token

verify token route

```js
router.get("/profile", verifyToken, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // Access user information from req.user
    const user: any = req.user;

    // Check if user is null or undefined
    if (!User) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: "User not found" });
    }

    const { id } = user;

    const userOne = await User.findOne({
      where: {
        id: id,
      },
    });
    // You can now use the user information as needed
    res.json(userOne);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal server error" });
  }
});
```

on my frontENd i am using vite
[front end code]

```js
const handleLogin = async (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://workdbackend.azurewebsites.net/auth/login",
        {
          method: "POST",
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
          credentials: "include",
          body: JSON.stringify({ username, password }),
        }
      );

      if (response.ok) {
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);
        dispatch(login(data));
      } else {
        // Login failed
        setError("שם משתמש או סיסמה לא נכונים");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Login error:", error);
    }
  };
```

its worked on my localHost but not its just dosnt work
git hub repo : https://github.com/henrix494/Claim_WORK
any help would be appreciated thank you.

u tryid playing with the
const corsOptions = {
allowedHeaders: [
"Origin",
"X-Requested-With",
"Content-Type",
"Accept",
"X-Access-Token",
"Authorization",
],

methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
origin: "https://claim-work.vercel.app",
credentials: true,
preflightContinue: false,
};
and it didnt work
the coociy being saved in post man but not in dev mode
i trid you change
res.cookie("jwt", token, {
httpOnly: false,
maxAge: maxAge * 1000,
sameSite: "none",
secure: true,
});
with not help

Comment: Please post the code as a text, and not a screenshot.

Comment: I added code sniped insted of pics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The error message indicates that there is an issue with Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS). This  occurs when a request is made from a frontend application (running on one origin) to a backend server (running on a different origin), and the server does not allow requests from the frontend origin.

```js
// app.js or server.js

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const User = require('./models/User'); // Import your User model
const { verifyToken } = require('./middleware/auth'); // Import your authentication middleware

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());

app.post("/auth/login", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { username, password } = req.body;
    const user = await User.findOne({
      where: {
        userName: username,
      },
    });

    if (user) {
      const match = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.getDataValue("passWord"));
      if (match) {
        const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user.id }, 'your_secret_key', { expiresIn: '1h' });
        res.cookie("jwt", token, {
          httpOnly: true,
          maxAge: 3600000, // 1 hour in milliseconds
          sameSite: "strict",
          secure: true,
        });
        res.status(200).json({ user });
      } else {
        res.status(400).json({ message: "Invalid username or password" });
      }
    } else {
      res.status(400).json({ message: "Invalid username or password" });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});

app.get("/auth/profile", verifyToken, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const userId = req.user.userId;
    const user = await User.findOne({
      where: {
        id: userId,
      },
    });
    res.json(user);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal server error" });
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

`npm install express body-parser cookie-parser bcrypt jsonwebtoken`

I followed the example  [code](https://github.com/ritik1009/JWT_DEMO) for the backend and added CORS by installing the `cors` package: `npm install cors`.

[image]

**Front end code:**

The below  React+Vite code is for implementing JWT authentication from reference by Ritik [khandelwal](https://medium.com/@ritikkhndelwal/jwt-authentication-in-the-frontend-enhancing-security-in-web-applications-ece418206b4f) .

```
project_name/
├── public/
│   └── index.html
├── src/
│   ├── components/
│   │   └── LoginForm.js
│   ├── services/
│   │   └── authService.js
│   ├── App.js
│   ├── index.js
│   └── App.css
└── package.json
```

**public/index.html:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>React JWT Authentication</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**src/components/LoginForm.jsx:**

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import authService from '../services/authService';

const LoginForm = () => {
    const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            await authService.login(username, password);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Login failed:', error);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className="login">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Username"
                    value={username}
                    onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
                />
                <input
                    type="password"
                    placeholder="Password"
                    value={password}
                    onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                />
                <button type="submit">Login</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
};

export default LoginForm;
```

**src/services/authService.js:**

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const authService = {
    login: async (username, password) => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:8800/api/login', { username, password });
            localStorage.setItem('accessToken', response.data.accessToken);
            localStorage.setItem('refreshToken', response.data.refreshToken);
            // You can also store user data like username in localStorage if needed
        } catch (error) {
            throw new Error('Login failed');
        }
    }
};

export default authService;
```

**src/index.js:**

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**src/App.js:**

```js
import React from 'react';
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm';
import './App.css';

function App() {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <h1>React JWT Authentication</h1>
            <LoginForm />
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

[image]

**Azure:**
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]